# Dynamically read ionic toggle value and post to database

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am displaying a list of names from the database, I need a toggle button in all list with respective to id and post them to the database.
How can I add toggle button in ionic and read it's value dynamically with the id.

stud.html

`<ion-item *ngFor="let list of getStudentList">
                <ion-label>{{list.Student_FirstName}}</ion-label>
                <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="list.Student_FirstName" (ionChange)="changeToggle()"></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>`

stud.ts

```
`

   changeToggle() {
    console.log(this.Student_FirstName + "is checked");
  }`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily pass the current item to `ionChange` function

```
<ion-toggle 
  [(ngModel)]="list.Student_FirstName" 
  (ionChange)="changeToggle(list)">
</ion-toggle>
```

**Component**

```
changeToggle(list){
    console.log(list.Id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to send a request in Angular way.
For your case, you need to specify the method to be 'POST' and send it to your Web-Service API (url) that deals with the database. Since it is POST method, don't forget to add 'data' in case your Web-Service needs variable(s) from this request.

In your *changeToggle()* function, you also need to check if it is toggled then you do something with your database, but if it is untoggled then you do a different thing or maybe do nothing. It's up to your requirement.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let list of getStudentList">
                <ion-label>{{list.Student_FirstName}}</ion-label>
                <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="list.Student_FirstName" (ionChange)="changeToggle(list)"></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>
```

and in your *changeToggle()* you take 1 input, which is the *list*.

```
changeToggle(list){
    console.log(list)
}
```

You should see the *list* object, which has its ID in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't get toggle selected id, I am struck in reading list ID's

Comment: @MadhankumarBK I edited the answer. Please see if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, it works but Whenever I changed toggle value in the place of {{list.Student_FirstName}} it displaying toggle boolean value (true when checked and false when unchecked).

Comment: because you use [(ngModel)]="list.Student_FirstName" and the fact that ion-toggle returns only true or false then you will see your variable list.Student_FirstName will only be either true or false.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to set these dynamic lists to be true(or toggled on) by default. And store these values (name and toggle value) in an array.

Comment: You initialize list.Student_FirstName to be true in the first place. If the answer solves your question, please accept it. That's how it works here in SO.

Comment: How to initialize it in the component, it showing error ';' expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181664/discussion-between-madhan-kumar-bk-and-holydragon).